# Sum a column value of all the previous observations

Tags: sql, databricks

I have a table that contains client_id, order_number and revenue. The idea is to sum the revenue up until each order number.

So, for example, a client has 3$ revenue in his first order and 2$ in his second. For his first loan it should return 3$ as revenue, but for the second 5$. It's rather a simple problem, but I have not found a solution yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the description you want a window sum(revenue) function partitioned by client_id and ordered by client_id and order_number

```
select client_id, order_number,revenue,
sum(revenue) over (partition by client_id ORDER BY client_id,order_number) as sum
       from your_table
       order by client_id
```

Sample data:

```
insert into your_table values (1,10,2);
insert into your_table values (1,20,3);
insert into your_table values (2,21,2);
insert into your_table values (2,22,10);
insert into your_table values (3,40,2);
```

Result:

```
CLIENT_ID | ORDER_NUMBER | REVENUE | SUM
1           10             2         2
1           20             3         5
2           21             2         2
2           22             10        12
3           40             2         2
```